# Correct Mathematical Grammar (Modulo)

Tags: number-theory, cryptography

Hello Guys I am wondering if this mathematical statement is correct **(not the result but the grammar)**.

> I want to find out if $35$ is a primitive root of $97$ which it is not as I calculated.

Is this correct?:

$$
35^{48} \pmod{97} \equiv 1 \implies  35 \ \text{not a primitive root in }  \mathbb Z_{97}^\ast
$$

> Example of fast exponentiation $35^{48} \bmod 97$

**Furthermore**:

Is this correct?:

$$
48_{(10)} = 110000_{(2)}  
$$

$$ 1: \ 35 \ \equiv \ 35  \pmod{97} $$
$$ 1: \ 35^2*35 \ \equiv \ 1\pmod{97}$$
$$ 0: \ 1^2 \ \equiv \ 1 \pmod{97}$$
$$ 0: \ 1^2 \ \equiv \ 1 \pmod{97}$$
$$ 0: \ 1^2 \ \equiv \ 1 \pmod{97}$$
$$ 0: \ 1^2 \ \equiv \ 1 \pmod{97}$$
$$35^{48} \bmod 97 \equiv 1$$

I have to know if this is correct if I write this as an answer in my exam or if it is grammatically wrong.

Comment: I don't understand what you wrote...it looks like you just wrote $1^2\equiv 1 \pmod {97}$ over and over.  Anyway, $35^3\equiv 1 \pmod {97}$.

Comment: Personally, I would avoid *wanna* and *gotta* on my exams. (1) "Is 35 a prime root of 97?  According to this calculation, it is not."   (2) "Fast exponentiation 35^48 mod 97."

Comment: @Gedgar Sorry, my bad I did not mean to write those quotes (yellow background) in my exam. I mean the mathematical grammar below.

Comment: @lulu I chose a bad example. Just Imagine it is not always the same equation :) Would it be okay to write it out like I did?

Comment: As I say, I can't follow what you wrote.  Perhaps you are using a notation for iterated squares that I am unfamiliar with.  Where do you even compute $35^2\equiv 61\pmod {97}$?  In any case, I would not accept what you wrote as a valid calculation.

Comment: @lulu Okay, thank you for taking your time. I saw this method in the solution from students from past exams so I was wondering if it is okay. Usually, this method is accepted (for the example above): $$ 35^{48} \ mod \ 97 \equiv (((((35)^2 *35)^2)^2)^2)^2 \equiv \ 1 $$

Comment: In this particular case, you should write down $$35^3\equiv 1\mod 97$$ because it already answers the question but is much easier to justify.

Comment: @Peter Alright, thank you Peter!

Comment: See [this online piece](https://mathlesstraveled.com/2018/08/18/modular-exponentiation-by-repeated-squaring/) for a nice explanation of the algorithm.

Comment: the formulation of the question could be better: "I would like to know whether $35$ is a primitive root of $\Bbb Z^\ast_{97}$. The following computation that $35^{48} \pmod{97}=1$ shows that this is not the case".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to write down the result of this exercise is :

A base $b$ is called a primitive root of a positive integer $n$ , if the smallest positive integer $k$ with $$b^k\equiv 1\mod n$$ is equal to $\varphi(n)$

In the example , $n$ is prime, hence $\varphi(n)=n-1=96$ But because of $$35^{48}\equiv 1\mod 97$$ $96$ is not the smallest $k$, hence $35$ is not a primitive root of $97$.

The calculation of the power modulo the prime is correct , but I agree lulu that you should write it down clearer (If you actually are supposed to calculate the result by hand).

Comment: Thanks! If I write it down like you to the point where you wrote $$ 35^{48} mod 97 \equiv 1 $$ and decide to write instead of "96 is not the smallest k, hence 35 is not a primitive root of 97. " this: $$ 35^{48} mod 97 \equiv 1 \to  35 \ \text{Not a prime root of }  \mathbb Z_{97}^* $$ Would that be valid? Just wondering :)

Comment: As I mentioned above in a comment, you should, if possible , show the smallest possible solution (then you can better justify it). How you exactly formulate the final answer depends on how the teacher expects it.